# Flowplayer, url is not defined

Tags: jquery, flowplayer

The following code works in a webbrowser, but not in iPhone (an excerpt of the code follows). I get the errror 'url is not defined'. What is the reason for this?

Here follows the code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/all/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://releases.flowplayer.org/js/flowplayer-3.2.13.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://releases.flowplayer.org/js/flowplayer.ipad-3.2.13.min.js"></script>

<script>

$( document ).ready(function() 


{

    $f(playerid, "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf", 
                    {
                    clip: {
                        autoPlay: false,
                        urlResolvers: 'brselect',
                        // preserve aspect ratios
                        scaling: 'fit',
                        bitrates: [

                            // use the 800 kbps item by default, the SD item, marked with sd: true
                            { url: videolink, bitrate: 800, sd: true, isDefault: true },

                            // this is the HD item, marked with hd: true
                            { url: hdlink, bitrate: 1600, hd: true }
                        ]
                    },
                    plugins: {
                        brselect: {
                            url: "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer.bitrateselect-3.2.14.swf",

                            // comment this out in production
                            onStreamSwitch: function (newItem) {
                               $f().getPlugin('content').setHtml("Switched to: " + newItem.streamName);
                            }
                        },
                        rtmp: {
                            url: "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.13.swf",
                            netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://s3b78u0kbtx79q.cloudfront.net/cfx/st'
                        },
                        content: {
                            url: "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer.content-3.2.9.swf",
                            top: 0, left: 0, width: 400, height: 150,
                            backgroundColor: 'transparent', backgroundGradient: 'none', border: 0,
                            textDecoration: 'outline',
                            style: {
                                body: {
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    fontFamily: 'Arial',
                                    textAlign: 'center',
                                    color: '#ffffff'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }



            ).ipad();





});
```

The attributes videolink and hdlink above have the values:

```
http://www.premanandasatsangtvarchive.org/international/2014-09-26enL.mp4 and http://www.premanandasatsangtvarchive.org/international/2014-09-26en.mp4
```

Url: `http://www.premanandasatsangtvarchive.org/sattv/sattvresponsive/complete_archive.html?language=en&nrofvideos=1&category=complete_english`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
I change the code so that it should work on iPhone (it doesn't need to work on browsers, since the code is used for an iPhone-app):

```
    <a href="${VideoLink}"    class="player playersize"
                id="player${id}">


                    <img id="posterframe${id}" class="widthscreen"
        src="${PosterFrame}"
        alt="${PosterFrame}" />
        </a>
```

In the script-file:

```
    var playeridTag = "#" + playerid;
        $(playeridTag).attr ("href", videolink);

        console.log ("player id is " + playerid);
        console.log ("videolink is " + videolink + "and hdlinkis " + hdlink + "title is " + titlewithhtml);

        $f(playerid, "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf",

        {
                clip: {
                    autoPlay: false,
                    urlResolvers: 'brselect',

                    // preserve aspect ratios
                    scaling: 'fit',
                    ipadUrl: videolink
                }

        }
        ).ipad();
```